# Is this ufw configuration correct?

Tags: networking, firewall, cloud, openstack, ufw

I have to link my openstack private cloud on a cloud management platform online. The cloud location is on my private ip (192.168.0.9) , i can't use that ip since the platform need a public ip so i wanna use the public ip that my provider gave me (87.13.180.182).

I need to configure NAT for this and i tried with ufw. So:

1. i decommented `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` on  `/etc/default/ufw`
2. i decommented `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on  `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`
3. i opened `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and created the following lines at beginning of script:

   *nat 
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]  
   -A PREROUTING -d 87.13.180.182 -j -DNAT -to--destination 192.168.0.9

// as i remember, 87.xx is my public ip and 192.xx is my private ip.

then i run ufw disable && ufw enable but the console say that there is an error on before.rules . Someone can help me fix the rule? I'm not so pro on ufw.

Comment: The contents of `/etc/ufw/before.rules` are not `ufw` rules but format by `iptables` when it saves rules.  So look up how iptables store and load data about firewall settings.